# Compare elements of two different size arrays and return boolean array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am still a beginner in Java and I would appreciate any help. 
I have two different arrays in size and I want to compare their elements. The return value is an int[] with the length of the bigger array. The int[] should contain 1s and 0s. 1 means that elements are identical and 0 not identical. Of course the rest of the int[] should be zeros because it is much longer.
Unfortunately I am getting this Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

What is wrong with my method?

```
public static int[] createVector(String[] longArr, String[] shortArr) {
    int l = Arrays.toString(longArr).length();
    int s = Arrays.toString(shortArr).length();
    int[] b = new int[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        b[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++) {
            if (longArr[i].equals(shortArr[j])) {
                b[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return b;

}
```

Comment: You only need one loop, not two. It should go from 0 to the shorter length and fill in "true" where necessary. The "tail" will stay at the default "false".

Comment: yes right, one loop. but still can't get my head around it. with for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) it didn't work.

Comment: Why do i need one loop? What i need to get is in this example: a boolean int[] of these two arrays {bob, charlie, john, lee, bruce, jack} and {john, jack}. My result should be {0,0,1,0,0,1}. That doesn't work with one loop.

Comment: Okay, I misread the question, I thought you wanted to compare identical entries at the same position. You are right, if you want to test do set intersection, you need two loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.toString(longArr).length();` returns length of `String` created by `Arrays#toString` which creates `String` something like `[a, b, c]` for String `array` `{"a", "b", "c"}`. Kindly note that length of array is `3` while `Arrays#toString#length` will return `>3`.

You can use `longArr.length`(*similarly* `shortArr.length`) to get `length` of an array.

Comment: It didn't work with longArr.length, i get length = 1. no idea why. sorry i don't have enough reputation to vote it up!

Comment: What is the value of `longArr` and `shortArr` ?

Comment: String[]. Is it possible to pass anything else?

Comment: @Palbear No I mean what you have inside `String[]` ? i.e. `String[] str = new String[]{"a","b"}` here str has length `2` and so if you are getting `1` then it means your `String` array has only one element.

Comment: I get the strings from a csv file and with StringBuilder i append all strings with commas and then yes I initialize it with  String[] baseVectorArray = {allStrings}. It is a very long String[]. when i do Arrays.toString(longArr).length(); i get 1430 length.

Comment: @Palbear I suggest you to print those arrays to console(you can use `Arrays.toString(lengthArr)` to print) before passing them to `createVector`.

Comment: thanks for the patience. When i print it to console i get the form [a,b,c]

Comment: I do allStrings = StringBuilder.toString() and put it in the array in that form String[] baseVectorArray = {allStrings}. And when i print it to console i get the form [a,b,c]

Comment: @Palbear Okay.  Problem is your `allString` is single String with value `a,b,c` so array will have only one `String`  `{"a,b,c"}` (length 1 ) and not `{"a", "b", "c"}`(length 3). You can use `String.split` i.e. `String[] baseVectorArray = allStrings.split(",");`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `longArr.length`, not `Arrays.toString(longArr).length()`. The latter returns a string representation of the array, not the actual array.

Also, it might be easier to create an array of zeroes with the length equal to that of the longer array. Then, you just need to iterate through the length of the smaller array, and change zeroes to ones as needed.

Comment: but when i do longArr.length i get length = 1 ! i don't know why but this is the reason i turned to Arrays.toString(longArr).length();

Answer (score 0):

You can access array's size with `length` property.

```
longArr.length
```

`Arrays.toString(longArr).length()` returns the length of string representation of the array, which might look `[more, like, this]` and contain extra characters.